# Openfire user stays online forever

Tags: php, push-notification, openfire

We are using Openfire 4.0.1 and we do have chatting functionality from application ios and android.

Issue is openfire user never gets offline from mobile end when user is in foreground your openfire user will be online once you go in background your user in openfire will get offline.

Now Issue is there are some users which never gets offline i have tried to login using other utilities like spark or spark-web and logout user manually still they appear online only in openfire admin console.

We do have push notifications functionality of offline users but some users who never be offline in that case push notification functionality never works!

Is there any way that this user can be forcefully offline.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to send manual Presence. If you didn't try, I'll explain in an answer

Comment: When you are saying that for an online user, you again logged-in using Spark and logged out from there. This will only logout Spark session not the previous one. As @MrPk has mentioned, you need to make sure if your application sends "presence type='unavailable'" packet. Also verify that in Openfire Admin, you have selected the option to disconnect idol users after a specific time.

Comment: @MrPk what do you mean by send manual presence ? From mobile application end they are already sending presence to openfire server when their application goes into background from foreground but still not they are getting offline. From Web i have tried installing spark-web login the user and logout user manually still they are online!

Comment: @ShoaibAhmadGondal Yes as mentioned above i have already tried login spark-web and logout manually still they are online. Can you please let me know from where i have to select the option to disconnect idol users after specific time ?

Answer (score 1):

For Disconnect Client Connections automatically.

Open your openfire web admin console and

Change settings from

**Server->Server settings->Client Connections Settings (sidebar)**

Change In **Idle Connections Policy**

[image]

Comment: I do have similar settings as you've given in above screenshot 360 seconds which means 6 minutes after 6 minutes user should be offline! but in my case those users are online since many days!

Comment: This is Work For me.You can ask this problem to https://community.igniterealtime.org/

Comment: Yes! The issue is with some users only! rest of the users behaviours are normal when users get into background mode users get offline and when foreground users got online.